# Cockcroft-Walton multiplier - capacitor sizes

Tags: voltage

When building a CW cascade people rarely talk about the size of the caps. Surely they must be a certain size for the circuit to work?

Comment: Why don't you simulate a circuit with real diodes having real parasitic capacitance and real reverse recovery time, then add a load and see how things pan out.

Comment: Have you done *any* searching for this answer with google? There are many excellent pages (and PDF files) discussing the design and implications of the capacitor choices on outcomes. If you have, expose your thinking. If not, do the legwork and come back to expose your thinking. Simple answer, though, is "Yes, capacitor size relates directly to common design goals."

Comment: It depends mostly on input frequency, number of stages, and the load impedance. What are those figures? And what's the application?

Comment: @mike Say for an input frequency of 1kHz, 3 stages and a 200kOhm load.

Comment: @KurtNewman .005 uf capacitors should work. What's the input voltage?